# Open results in new tab (Javascript)

Tags: javascript

I got an dynamic page with results, and the problem is that the links appearing there won't open on a new tab, this is the code but i am not being able to sort it out.

I would like that when a page (link) is clicked to have it opened on a new tab instead of going direct to the site.

BTW: English is not my native language, i hope i was able to describe it right.

```
   var updateResultsHtml = function() 
{
      for ( var i = 0, exists = 0, elements = []; i < results.length; i++ ) {
         exists += (statuses.success.indexOf(results[i].status) >= 0 ? 1 : 0);
         elements.push(appendChildren(createElement('div', ['class', 'col3']), [
            createElement('a', ['href', results[i].url, 'data-value', results[i].message], results[i].url.replace(/(https?\:\/\/)?(www\.)?/i, ''))
         ]));
      }
      resultsUsername.innerText   = username;
      resultsUsername2.innerText  = username;
      resultsPercentage.innerText = Math.round((exists / total) * 100) + '%';
      removeChildren(resultsParent);
      appendChildren(resultsParent, elements);
      togglePanel(resultsPanel);
   };

   var getExistence = function() {
      httpRequest('POST', 'existence.php', ['content-type', 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded'], 'index=' + index + '&username=' + username, function(data) {
         if ( index < total ) {
            ++index;
            results.push(JSON.parse(data));
            updateProccessingHtml();
            getExistence();
         }
         else {
            updateResultsHtml();
         }
      });
   };
```

Also my other question is related to the submit button, it has to be clicked in which case the code won't recognize Enter button, what would be the change to make it recognize the enter and make it submittable also when Enter is pressed.

```
submitButton.onclick = function() {
  index    = 0;
  results  = [];
  username = usernameInput.value;
  if ( username.length > 0 ) {
     window.location.href   = '//' + window.location.host + window.location.pathname + '#' + username;
     usernameInput.disabled = true;
     submitButton.disabled  = true;
     getExistence();
  }
```

Comment: For your second newly added question, simply add an event listener for the "keyup" event, monitor the event to see if `event.keyCode === 13` (enter key) and if so, trigger your click event `document.getElementById("myBtn").click();`. Or even better, you can move that `onClick` function and make both event listeners call that function.

Comment: Could you please be more specific. What would be the change on the code?

Comment: Move the code from inside your `submitButton.onclick` to a new function; lets call it `doStuff`. Then you can handle enter key presses using `myInputField.addEventListener('keypress', function (e) { if (e.keycode === 13) { doStuff(); }});`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can force your hyperlinks to open in a new tab using the attributed-text `target` attribute.

> Target specifies where to display the linked URL. It is a name of, or keyword for, a browsing context: a tab, window, or iframe.

---

#### Syntax:

`<a target="_blank|_self|_parent|_top|framename">`

---

#### Attribute Values

The following keywords have special meanings:

- **_self**: Load the URL into the same browsing context as the current one. This is the default behavior.
- **_blank**: Load the URL into a new browsing context. This is usually a tab, but users can configure browsers to use new windows instead.
- **_parent**: Load the URL into the parent browsing context of the current one. If there is no parent, this behaves the same way as _self.
- **_top**: Load the URL into the top-level browsing context (that is, the "highest" browsing context that is an ancestor of the current one, and has no parent). If there is no parent, this behaves the same way as _self.

---

#### Modifying your example to open links in a new tab

You can simply add the `target` attribute to your `createElement` function arguments, as follows:

```
createElement('a', ['href', results[i].url, 'target', '_blank', 'data-value', results[i].message], results[i].url.replace(/(https?\:\/\/)?(www\.)?/i, ''))
```

Comment: Thanks for the fast reply,

That would crash the results, could you please be more specific and quote the code i provided with the changes.

Comment: See my edited post. Simply throw the `target` and `_blank` arguments in your element constructor.

Comment: You're a life saver thank you, i edited my post with another question, what would be the correction?

Comment: For your additional question, please create a new post.